# Convergence of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\ln\left(\frac{n^{-a}}{\sin(n^{-a})}\right)$ where $a>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need help with this series. In order to meet the necessary convergence condition I know that $a$ has to be more than zero. I tried to use comparison test with $1/n^2$ but the limit seems to be infinity. The solution should be that it converges if $a>0.5$. Any suggestions?

> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\ln\left(\frac{\frac{1}{n^a}}{\sin(\frac{1}{n^a})}\right), 
>  \space a>0$$

Someone suggested use to Taylor... but i formally did not study it in school yet so  i would be grateful for hints without Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that as $x\to 0$,
$$\ln\left(\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\right)
=-\ln\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)=-\ln\left(\frac{x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)}{x}\right)\\=-\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)\right)=\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2).$$
which implies that for $a>0$, 
$$\ln\left(\frac{\frac{1}{n^a}}{\sin(\frac{1}{n^a})}\right)\sim \frac{1}{6n^{2a}}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Edit. If Taylor expansion is not allowed, you may also evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\ln\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)}{x^2}
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x}\right)}{\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x}}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}\\=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\ln\left(1+y\right)}{y}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{3x^2}=1\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{6x}=\frac{1}{6}$$
by using Hopital's Theorem.

Comment: @Emanuel Frátrik I edited my answer with a Hopital's approach.

Comment: It looks very helpful but i am not sure why u put there x^2 in denominator of limit

Comment: Of course without Taylor you have to guess the "right" power $x^2$.

Comment: Thanks.Like I see i have to practise guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $x\to0$ we have
$$\csc{(x)}=\frac1x+\frac{x}6+o(x)$$
$$\ln{(1+x)}=x+o(x)$$
So our summand is asymptotic to
$$\begin{align}
\ln{\left(\frac1{n^a}\left(n^a+\frac1{6n^a}+o\left(\frac1{n^a}\right)\right)\right)}
&=\ln{\left(1+\frac1{6n^{2a}}+o\left(\frac1{n^{2a}}\right)\right)}\\
&=\frac1{6n^{2a}}+o\left(\frac1{n^{2a}}\right)\\
\end{align}$$
Then note that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{6n^{2a}}+o\left(\frac1{n^{2a}}\right)\right)$$
is a $p$-series and converges if and only if $a\gt\frac12$.

Comment: It looks very simple when i can use Taylor expansion but unfortunately i must not to use it during examination due to we didn't formally study it  in school yet

Comment: Then just use the comparison test with $b_n=1/n^{2a}$ and you should get $a_n/b_n\to\frac16$ hence the series converges if and only if the sum of $1/n^{2a}$ converges.